# Cannot change Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Community edition, and need to add C++ to it. But VS doesn't let me add it. In fact, it doesn't let me change it from Control Panel, either. I cannot uninstall it. Every time, I get the following:

> Setup blocked
>
> The computer needs to be restarted before setup can continue

Comment: Make sure you restart and not shut down and then start it again, and it should let you continue.

Comment: But it does not let me continue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio does not come installed with C++ by default. Visit the Microsoft link below to see if that helps.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/60k1461a.aspx

If the above linked information does not solve the issue, ensure you have rebooted you PC. Not all libraries are functional until a reboot. Also, provide your OS. Visual Studio can be temperamental depending on Windows Version.

As for the uninstall issue, you can force an uninstall via an elevated command prompt. Enter the code below and change the C: to the appropriate drive you have Visual Studio on.

```
C:\vs_community.exe /uninstall /force
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of course, I rebooted many times. I understand that I needed to add it, but the problem is that VS is not letting me do it, saying "Setup blocked". I have Windows 7.

Comment: And command prompt uninstall also doesn't work with the same "Setup blocked" error.

Comment: Wow. When you go to Programs and try to Change/ uninstall, does anything come up?

Comment: Yes. The same "Setup blocked" message. I spent the whole day with Microsoft support guys. It seems like it was because Windows was trying to upgrade to Windows 10 without my invitation. In general, Windows Update was not working at all due to that. Now it is checking for updates for several hours already, and I don't know what the outcome will be.

Comment: Hopefully MS can resolve the issues. I had issues with my Windows 10 desktop a couple of weeks ago. Supoort never resolved the issue. I had corrupt system files to include the updater. Never had a virus. I ended up switching to Linux (Mint 18 "Sara" Cinnamon). Best decision I ever made.